# why all android permissions does not exist in Qt creator?

Tags: android, qt, permissions, android-manifest, qt-creator

I am developing an application in Qt creator that needs permission `android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` but this does not exist in AndroidManifest.xml menu.How can i add it?

Comment: You can add directly to Android Manifest Application tag. Still you can't get it means share you Android Manifest File.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add this because there is **no such permission** as "android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" in Android.

An app already has permission by default to the only Internal Storage locations where it is allowed to write.